# sed command in linux.how to use sed to replace only first n ocuurences

Tags: bash, unix

I want to replace only first four occurences of LC-COUNT=1.how can i do that.

```
sed -i "s/LC-COUNT=1/LC-COUNT=$LC_COUNT/1,4"  file.txt
```

Comment: replace by LC-COUNT=$LC_COUNT

Comment: With `sed -e 's/LC-COUNT=1/LC-COUNT=\$LC_COUNT/' file.txt` I am able to replace all occurrences. No luck in replacing only first four occurrences though. I'll let you know if I am able to figure this out.

Answer (score 4):

Try this -

```
sed -e '0,/LC-COUNT=1/s//LC-COUNT=\$LC_COUNT/' file.txt > output.txt
```

Running it only once will replace first occurrences of `LC-COUNT=1` by `LC-COUNT=$LC_COUNT` and will put the output output.txt file. Note : You will have to escape **$** char first.

You are going to have to run it **four times**. But next time, consider output.txt as the original file, I mean do the replace in output.txt.

I think finding and replacing first **N** occurrences is not possible with `sed`.

In vim you do the similar kind of thing like -

```
:%s/LC-COUNT=1/LC-COUNT=\$LC_COUNT/gc
```

There `gc` option will ask you for confirmation on each find-replace. You can

Answer (score 0):

This is better suited for awk.

Consider this awk command:

```
awk -F= '$1=="LC-COUNT" && c<=4 {$2="=$LC_COUNT";c++}1' OFS= file
```